# Where can I learn the cakephp without the documentation as the documentation is hard to follow for beginners?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

Please give some link so that I can learn from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to go through the basics of Model, View and Controller first. And then try their Blog Tutorial on your local server to be accustomed with the basic code structure, and how it works with the database tables.

You'll come across a lot of keywords, commands, functions etc as you go through the Blog tutorial, so look it up one by one to understand their functionality. I think that'd come in handy for a beginner.